# Custom PS4 joystick with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, joystick

I am acquiring a Logitech G29 for my PS4 and I want to have an external handbreak. The handbrake only needs an input when active, so no "pressure level" or something like that required, only "on" or "off".

I have come around a few answers such as [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/11937/arduino-analog-joystick), but I am not sure how to make it work on PS4 (and even if it needs some changes what so ever).

I don't have enough knowlegde to ask the correct questions, so I am asking for directions on basically how to send an arduino signal so the PS4 interprets as a joystick command (which in game I will configure as the handbrake option).

I am somewhat aware about the necessity of a custom library, but nothing more than that, not even what that really means to be honest.

The drawing bellow is somewhat the scheme for my project. And it is based on what I understood from [this post](https://amp-reddit-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/amp.reddit.com/r/simracing/comments/7ibcgz/my_handbrake_and_seq_shifter_setup_for_ps4_with/?usqp=mq331AQHKAFQArABIA%3D%3D&amp_js_v=0.1#aoh=16057402017102&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=Fonte%3A%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fsimracing%2Fcomments%2F7ibcgz%2Fmy_handbrake_and_seq_shifter_setup_for_ps4_with%2F).

[image: External handbreak scheme]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do right as the reddit post says: Buy an Arduino with native USB capability (Leonardo or Micro for example). Then read the input from the handbreak switch. Then send keystrokes with the [Keyboard library](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/) to the computer. Would that answer your question? If not, where exactly lies the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a good start. I have access to an Arduino UNO, so I will check about this USB capability. About the Keyboard library, you said "send keystrokes ... to the computer"... I actually need to send it to my PS4, is the approach the same? Does the library change? Again, thanks for the repply

Comment: The Uno has no native USB capability. You need a different Arduino. And computer and PS4 are equivalent here. The PS4 seems to support normal USB keyboards, just like a computer. When using the keyboard library, the Arduinos USB interfaces behaves like a normal USB keyboard. Thats exactly the way, that the reddit post took.

Comment: Thanls for the directions, I think I'll be able to continue from here. If I may ask one last thing, since I currently only have UNO, any way to implement the USB componet? I am not sure it even is a component, i'm really new to this - or any other way around to use the UNO?

Comment: The ability of using the Arduino as a Keyboard/Mouse depends on the Chip. For example, the Arduino Leonardo has a AtMega32U4, which has the ability but the Arduino UNO has a AtMega328P that isn't able to wok as a USB input device.